# Entity Framework 4.0 Function Import - Why does it not show up as a method in my object context?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I have a stored procedure that I've mapped in my entity framework model (trying to do my first one), and I've specified a function import. The stored procedure returns a data set as the result, which is mapped to a complex type in my function import. I'm using VS.NET 2010.

I think that I've done all of the typical stuff required, i.e. like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx. There are no model errors either.

Is there anything else that I need to do in order to be able to call my function import? Has anyone else had a similar issue where they've created a function import that returns a complex type, yet it didn't show up as a callable function from the ObjectContext? If not, is there anything that you may recommend I look into in order to further investigate?

Edit: 
I'm just executing my stored procedures directly with the entity framework direct execution method, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358758.aspx. The nice part is it still auto-maps to my complex types for me. Although I would love to use the function import approach...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not show as method on `ObjectContext` but on derived generated class. If you are using `ObjectContext` directly you must call function import by using `ExecuteFunction`.

Comment: I'm using my derived class that inherits from ObjectContext, but no luck, it must be something simple that I'm missing. I'll try your suggested approach though to see if that works, although I would prefer to be able to call the function import directly.

Comment: I still haven't been able to resolve my issue, but since your general commment about function imports is correct I've marked it as accepted. I'll have to fiddle around a little longer with it.

Comment: @Shan: You must post more details if you want further help. It should work, your scenario must be somehow specific.

Comment: I will as a follow up question after I do some more digging

Answer (score 8):

I ended up with the problem and I fixed it by right-clicking on the ***.Context.tt file in my Solution Explorer and choosing "Run Custom Tool".

I've had to do that a lot to get updates to show up in my model object.

Comment: I was just experiencing the exact issue described here, well even simpler in that I was mapping to standard (non-custom) entities. The method with the given FunctionImport name won't show up until I did the "Run Custom Tool". Thanks!

Comment: +1. Sometimes stupid things do it for you when working with MS tools. :)